# Get property value from classes that inherit from a particular type

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to get all id properties from classes which inherit from "ClassA".

My current code is

```
IEnumerable<string> ids = dll
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(q => q.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ClassA)))
            .Select(q => q.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(q, null).ToString());
```

However I keep getting the exception "Object does not match Target Type".

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: I would expect a `NullReferenceException` in this case.Because you are calling `GetType` method on a `Type` instance, and `Type` doesn't have an `Id` property.

Answer (score 1):

`q` is a `Type` instance. You are passing a `Type` instance to `GetValue` method instead of an instance of the particular class.

If you want to get value of some instance properties then you need instances. If your properties are *static* just pass null to `GetValue` method.

Comment: what code example ? what are you trying to achieve ? do you have any instance ? where did you declare them ? if you don't have any instance what values do you want to get ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to drop the GetType() on q.

q is a Type and in the Select you're calling q.GetType(), which will be of Type 'Type'
Try:

```
Select(q => q.GetProperty("Id").GetValue(q, null).ToString())
```

Edit:
    `Select(q => g.GetProperty("Id"))` will return an object of type PropertyInfo.
Then call GetValue(obj) for any object of type q.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried that but seems to give the same error.

Comment: It's the q part of the GetValue parameters it's not happy about. If I remove the GetValue it would happily return all of the types of the properties.

Comment: You are passing q as a parameter for GetValue() q is an object of Type 'Type'